# How to attach a restlet to a partiular URL path scheme (HTTP or HTTPS)?

Tags: java, restlet

I'm using Restlet 2.3.2

I'd like to run a Restlet server with both HTTP and HTTPS protocols, but I'd like to attach a different restlet to each one. For exemple, `restletUnsecure` to HTTP but `restletSecure` to HTTPS. Actualy, attaching only one restlet to the path `/test` works properly.

I tried putting the scheme in the URI while attaching, like this, but this does not work (I get a page not found with my browser) :

```
Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTPS, 8443);
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8080);
[...]
component.getDefaultHost().attach("https://localhost:8443/test", restletSecure);
component.getDefaultHost().attach("http://localhost:8080/test", restletUnsecure);
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should define specific virtual hosts HTTP and HTTPS requests, as described below:

```
Component component = (...)

// HTTPS
VirtualHost hostHttps
      = new VirtualHost(component.getContext());
component.getHosts().add(hostHttps);
hostHttps.setHostScheme("https");

Restlet restletSecure = (...)
hostHttps.attachDefault(restletSecure);

// HTTP
VirtualHost hostHttp
      = new VirtualHost(component.getContext());
component.getHosts().add(hostHttp);
hostHttp.setHostScheme("http");

Restlet restletUnsecure = (...)
hostHttp.attachDefault(restletUnsecure);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi, I think it should be hostHttps.attachDefault(restletSecure); and hostHttp.attachDefault(restletUnsecure);